# Use variable in jQuery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a function which is called by moving round on the page, and depending where you are it sends you do a different element.

So

```
function changeFrame() {
  $('#f2').stop(true,true).hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 400);
 }
```

Which works great, but I want to change the target ID on the fly, so I though I would be able to call the function with a variable and use that, but it doesn't work.

```
function changeFrame(requestedFrame) {
      $(requestedFrame).stop(true,true).hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 400);
    }
```

Everything else is the same, and I have used 
I have also tried it like this:

```
  $('requestedFrame')
```

Lastly, to make sure I am passing it the variable correctly, which I am I did this

```
    alert(requestedFrame);
```

Example *requestedFrame* string

```
f2
```

Comment: $('#requestedFrame') not $('requestedFrame')

Comment: Are you calling the function with `changeFrame('#someId')` or `changeFrame('.someClass')` or `changeFrame(someElement)`? If not, your are doing it wrong.

Comment: That tries to then go to the element with the id of #requestedFrame not the frame requested through the function variable

Comment: @FelixKling Yes changeFrame('#someID');

Comment: Then it should work. Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo which reproduces your problem.

Comment: @FelixKling in the process of creating the fiddle I tried setting it as an object as one of the answers suggested, worked a treat!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's difficult to tell what requestedFrame is, but if it's a string id, then you need to select it with:

```
$('#' + requestedFrame).stop(true,true).hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 400);
```

If it's already a jQuery object, then you can drop the wrapper altogether:

```
requestedFrame.stop(true,true).hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 400);
```

Comment: requestedFrame is a string such as "f2" short and simple but not an ID/jQuery object

Answer (score 2):

$() in jquery accepts objects.. try calling the function like:

```
changeFrame(this);
```

and then using this 'obj' variable inside the function:

```
function changeFrame(obj) {
$(obj).stop(true,true).hide("blind", { direction: "vertical" }, 400);
}
```